# SQL Server: Execution time is different in View and SQL editor with same select query

Tags: sql-server, view, inner-join

I've a a view joined on multiple tables. When I execute the the select statement in SQL editor the same statement is taking 0.0055 secs and the view with same select statement taking more than 5 secs to execute. Basically the SQL query is same but I'm wondering what could be the issue? All necessary indexes are updated in the table used.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the FIRST time u run the code in editor, the query takes 0.0055sec.. the sql server, after first run, creates a "Memory table" with query results.. And if your query doesn't change, you only get this results.

To try this, just try to run your query in a new SQL Editor window. If it really takes 0.0055 sec, then we'll need to look a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment but I was able to resolve the issue by removing 'order by' in the view.